# How to change the ionic4 ion-back-button default function?

Tags: back-button, ionic4

```
import { IonBackButtonDelegate } from '@ionic/angular'

class TestButton {
  @ViewChild('backbutton') backButtonDelegate: IonBackButtonDelegate

  this.backButtonDelegate.onClick = (en: Event) => {
    console.log("test")
  }
}
```

I want to change default function of the 'ion-back-buttom', but it seem didn't work, could someone do some help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting it wrong. This should work -

```
import { IonBackButtonDelegate } from '@ionic/angular'

class TestButton {
  @ViewChild(IonBackButtonDelegate, { static: false }) backButtonDelegate: IonBackButtonDelegate;

  this.backButtonDelegate.onClick = (en: Event) => {
    console.log("test")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way. However the event will not trigger for android physical back button clicks.

In template :

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button (click)="back()">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

In component :

```js
back() {
    // Do what you want here
}
```